# Stop use of Add and Remove methods in subclass on the abstract class' List property

Tags: c#, winforms, subclass, subclassing

I have an abstract class with a int List field and property I want to control because it needs to always be sorted.

```
public abstract partial class FindAndReplace : Form {

    private readonly List<int> _columnsToSearch = new List<int>();
    public List<int> ColumnsToSearch { get { return _columnsToSearch; } }

    public void AddToColumnsToSearch(int intToAdd) {
        _columnsToSearch.Add(intToAdd);
        _columnsToSearch.Sort();
    }

    protected abstract void ColumnCheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);

    ...
}
```

Here is the subclass of FindAndReplace. I want to force it to use FindAndReplace's method AddToColumnsToSearch, but in the subclass, the Add method on ColumnsToSearch is still available. I was under the impression that making _columnsToSearch readonly and only giving the get method on ColumnsToSearch would hide away any methods like Add and Remove on ColumnsToSearch.

```
public partial class StepsTableFindAndReplace : FindAndReplace {

    protected override void ColumnCheckBox_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

        //get the columnIndex (removed the actual "get" code to keep simpler)
        int colIndex = 0;

        //can still use Add and Remove, want it to be 
        //AddToColumnsToSearch(colIndex) and RemoveFromColumnsToSearch(colIndex)
        if (cb.Checked) ColumnsToSearch.Add(colIndex);
        else            ColumnsToSearch.Remove(colIndex);
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong/not understanding?

The answer for this question gave me this solution (that isn't working)... [C# get and set properties for a List Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196117/c-sharp-get-and-set-properties-for-a-list-collection)

Comment: You can build your own class implementing IList<> and implement your needs when calling Add method

Answer (score 1):

The `readonly` modifier only prevents reassignment, and using a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` does not do what you want as you want to alter it at runtime.

You can instead change the the `private List<int>` to a `protected SortedSet<int>`, which sorts itself upon modification:

```
public abstract partial class FindAndReplace : Form 
{
    protected readonly SortedSet<int> _columnsToSearch = new SortedSet<int>();

    // ...
```

Then you can access it from the derived class directly:

```
if (cb.Checked)
{
    _columnsToSearch.Add(colIndex);
}
else 
{
    _columnsToSearch.Remove(colIndex);
}
```

And then return a *new* collection upon getter access, for example through `ToArray()`:

```
public IEnumerable<int> ColumnsToSearch 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return _columnsToSearch.ToArray(); 
    } 
}
```

Note that the latter creates a disconnected scenario: accessing `ColumnsToSearch` gives you a copy of `_columnsToSearch` *at that moment*, contrary to a `ReadOnlyCollection`, which is a wrapper over the `List<T>`.

Comment: Would there be a better way of keeping the List sorted than forcing the custom Add and Remove methods?

Comment: This approach keeps the list sorted and does not require custom Add and Remove methods, so I don't understand your question.

Comment: The CheckChanged event handler is in the subclass so _columnsToSearch would not be accessible to do Add or Remove. This event handler has to be in the subclassed version because the method of getting the column index is not possible for the abstract class to do.

Comment: Then declare `_columnsToSearch` as `protected`.

Comment: but then the list isn't being sorted because it's still just directly adding to the list without regard to it's order? The only place I currently have anything to sort it is in AddToColumnToSearch. if _columnsToSearch.Add(colIndex) is done then _columnsToSearch.sort() is not executed after the add.

Comment: I like the solution that you helped me get to with the ReadOnlycollection in the get method. Thought, I am still using the AddToColumnsToSearch instead of doing _columnsToSearch.Add(colIndex) because _columnsToSearch is not accessible in the subclass.

Comment: I still don't quite understand what you're asking, but your question seems to be answered in [Is there a list that is sorted automatically in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721889/is-there-a-list-that-is-sorted-automatically-in-net).

Comment: That very easily fixes my problem, though I also liked your original solution. You should edit your answer to SortedList or I can edit it for you to use AddToColumnsToSearch which added to _columnsToSearch and sorted it and had ColumnsToSearch return the ReadOnlyCollection (return type in your answer needs changed to ReadOnlyCollection).

Comment: @Blake but `SortedList` is a key-value pair list, and has no `Add(T)` but an `Add(TKey, TValue)` method. Alternatively, you can also just sort when the list is actually enumerated, instead of upon modification. Also, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is an `IList<T>`.

Comment: I used SortedList<int, string> which actually worked really well. I can store the string as the column's name. This actually made it so I could put the CheckChanged event in the abstract class and I can get the column to add or remove based on the checkbox's Name. (checkbox's Name has to be the same as the column's Name in the DataTable).

Comment: Alright, happy to be of help. You can add that as your own answer if you want, please don't edit answers to add your own information. :)

Comment: just wanted to give you the code I used since you helped me get to it and I thought you'd want the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try exposing `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` instead of `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `readonly` modifier does not make collections read-only; it just prevents setting the field outside the constructor.  The public property should be exposed as `IReadOnlyCollection<int>` and the backing field should be made `protected` to allow subclasses to modify the list.